# Should I use singular or plural when describing the same thing in different year

Tags: tense, singular-vs-plural

| Year | share of collected solid waste in total solid waste generated |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 25% |
| 2005 | 30% |
| 2010 | 35% |
| 2015 | 40% |
| 2020 | 45% |

I want to describe the data inside the above table, but I am not sure I am using the correct tense and form of the noun

> The solid waste collection **rates** **had been** increasing from 2000 to 2020

> This region **saw an increasing rate** of solid waste collection over the past two decades.

Comment: waste collection rate or rate of waste collection is ok.  The verb should be simple past in the first sentence. Is this solid waste?

Comment: @Lambie, thank you for your comment and question. Yes, it is municipal solid waste. But I am still not clear, do you mean there is no difference using rate or rates? and why simple past? I chose to use past participle because I think the table talks about a period in the past. No?

Comment: As phrased, the question answers itself: one thing changing over a course of years is, well, one thing.  Whether *those rates are different* or *that rate is variable* doesn't depend on the grammar.  Rather, that grammar choice depends on how you intend to present and use the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid waste collection rates had been increasing from 2000 to 2020, and then slowed in 2021. [For example].

You only use past perfect if there is another action in the simple past **preceding it.**

AND:
This region saw increasing rates of solid waste collection over the past two decades.

**If the two decades are not yet over:**

This region has seen increasing rates of solid waste collection over the past two decades.

For rates, you have to decide if you mean all of them or individual.

**Re rates:**
Right, so. In economics, generally, if you have different years, each year has a rate, ergo, for more than one year, it's plural.

But if you take an average of something over a period of time (10 years), for example, you say rates since you are referring to the rate by **periods of ten years**. The rates of inflation from 1920 to 1950 were higher than [whatever].

Comment: thank you again Lambie. Now I understand the tense part. Re "rate" and "rates" in a sentence, for instance, "this region has seen increasing rates of solid waste collection", if using "rates", the emphasis is on different values of the rate. If using "rate", the emphasis is on the type of rate, ie., solid waste collection rate. Am I right?

Comment: @Elizabeth  actually FAILED to answer that. See my amended answer. :)